# What does assigning self to a variable in Python Class mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tree

While I was learning Tree data structure in python, I came across this code:

```py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None

    def get_level(self):
        level = 0
        p = self.parent
        while p:
            level += 1
            p = p.parent

        return level

    def print_tree(self):
        spaces = ' ' * self.get_level() * 3
        prefix = spaces + "|__" if self.parent else ""
        print(prefix + self.data)
        if self.children:
            for child in self.children:
                child.print_tree()

    def add_child(self, child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children.append(child)

def build_product_tree():
    root = TreeNode("Electronics")

    laptop = TreeNode("Laptop")
    laptop.add_child(TreeNode("Mac"))
    laptop.add_child(TreeNode("Surface"))
    laptop.add_child(TreeNode("Thinkpad"))

    cellphone = TreeNode("Cell Phone")
    cellphone.add_child(TreeNode("iPhone"))
    cellphone.add_child(TreeNode("Google Pixel"))
    cellphone.add_child(TreeNode("Vivo"))

    tv = TreeNode("TV")
    tv.add_child(TreeNode("Samsung"))
    tv.add_child(TreeNode("LG"))

    root.add_child(laptop)
    root.add_child(cellphone)
    root.add_child(tv)

    root.print_tree()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    build_product_tree()
```

It was a tutorial from Codebasics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r_XR9fUPhQ&list=PLeo1K3hjS3uu_n_a__MI_KktGTLYopZ12&index=9

Now my question is why in the 25th line there is `child.parent = self` what does it mean or why should I have to do that.

Comment: It means the same as assigning any other value to a variable. `self` refers to the current instance (`this` in some languages).

Comment: You can access `child` from the `parent` (which creates the `child`) but cannot access `parent` from the `child` unless you assign the reference to the `parent` to a property of the `child`

Comment: `self` is a reference to the current object. Just as you are adding `child` to the list of `self`'s children, you are setting `child`'s parent attribute to its new parent.

Comment: @chepner Thnx for your answer. Now I understood very well. Thnx again. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` references the current instance. This line of code will tell the child that it's parent is the current instance.